# Email Alerts in Flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow, email-alert

I've set up a screenflow which sends an email alert via flow.

I've found a weird issue where users with a certain profile can't send emails when the email alert is set to "User Current Users Email address"

I've looked through the profile to find which permissions differ but im at a loss.

Does anyone know which permission this profile is lacking? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Caused by Users emails not being verified.

Fixed by sending password reset emails

These emails fail silently and don't even show in the EMail Log Files

Answer (score 0):

Check that

- The users have access to the email template folder
- The profiles have access to the object/fields in the flow, record level access, or the flow is running in system context
- the users have the Flow User checkbox enabled